# Python 3 how to replace 2 characters in one

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

```
def double(text_var):
    for i in range(len(text_var)):
        if text_var[i]=='a' and text_var[i+1]=='b':
            text_var=text_var.replace(text_var[i],'0')
            text_var=text_var.replace(text_var[i+1],'') 
    return text_var
```

i'm trying to achieve something like this -->  ab = 0
both characters replaced by one character ( zero in that case )

Comment: Why are you trying to do the replacement of two characters yourself? You obviously already know ``str.replace``, which can do this for you.

Answer (score 3):

This should work fine:

```
def double(text_var):
    return text_var.replace("ab", "0")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the reasons your code doesn't work:

> 1. Python indexes begin at `0`, so they end one unit before the length of the array. That's why you get an `string index out of range`. To fix that, change

```
for i in range(len(text_var))
```

> to

```
for i in range(len(text_var)-1)
```

> 2. This part of your code:

```
        text_var=text_var.replace(text_var[i],'0')
        text_var=text_var.replace(text_var[i+1],'')
```

> Although you passed `text_var[i]` and `text_var[i+1]` into the `replace()` method, the values are evaluated there, so python will just find all the `a`s and `b`s, not necessarily adjacent to each others, to replace.

---

The correct way to approach this is like this:

```
def double(text_var):
    return text_var.replace("ab", "0")
```